# removeChild not working, but no error

Tags: javascript

removeChild and function call are not working.  I've looked at all other questions but can't figure out why.  Here's my code...

```js
var gameContainer = document.getElementById("game-container");

function startGame() {
 var startButton = document.getElementById("start-button");
 gameContainer.removeChild(startButton);      //button disappears
            
 var logo = document.createElement("IMG");
 logo.src = "http://img.qj.net/uploads/articles_module/2048/poke_2Dlogo.gif";
 gameContainer.appendChild(logo);
 logo.id="logo";          //logo appears
 var sublogo = document.createElement("P");
 var sublogoText = document.createTextNode("Yellow Diamond Version");
 sublogo.appendChild(sublogoText);
 gameContainer.appendChild(sublogo);
 sublogo.id="sub-logo";
 var sublogoImg = document.createElement("IMG");
 sublogoImg.src = "https://41.media.tumblr.com/6f25c533c98bfc58790eba699862437d/tumblr_inline_o0nqr4s49p1sp23ws_540.png"
 gameContainer.appendChild(sublogoImg);
 sublogoImg.id = "sub-logo-img";

 setTimeout(preLogoFade,3000);
 function preLogoFade() {
  var logoOpacity = .9;
  var logoInterval = setInterval(function(){LogoFade()},100);
   function LogoFade() {
    logo.style.opacity=logoOpacity;
    sublogo.style.opacity=logoOpacity;
    sublogoImg.style.opacity=logoOpacity;
    logoOpacity-=.1;
    if(logoOpacity==0){
     gameContainer.removeChild(logo);
     gameContainer.removeChild(sublogo);
     gameContainer.removeChild(sublogoImg);
     professorOpen();
    }
   }          //LogoFade Function End
 }            //preLogoFade Function End
}             //startGame Function End

function professorOpen() {
 clearInterval(logoInterval);
 gameContainer.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/steven-universe/images/9/90/Yellow_Diamond_by_Lenhi.png/revision/latest?cb=20160109203916)";
}
```

```css
body {
 background-color:black;
}
#game-container{
 width:800px; height:700px;
 border:1px solid white;
 margin:0 auto;
 background-image:none;
 background-size:cover;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#start-button{
 width:100px; height:40px;
 position:relative; top:330px; left:350px;
 background-color:red;
 border:1px solid white; border-bottom-width:2px; border-top-width:0px;
 font-size:125%;
}
#start-button:hover{
 color:white;
}
#logo{
 width:100%; height:300px;
 position:relative;
 z-index:3;
}
#sub-logo{
 text-shadow: 1px 0 5px white, -1px 0 5px white, 0 1px 5px white, 0 -1px 5px white;
 color:#FEFF00;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:50px;
 position:relative; bottom:70px; left:15px;
 z-index:2;
}
#sub-logo-img{
 width:550px; height:405px;
 margin:auto;
 position:relative; left:140px; bottom:170px;
 z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <title>Game</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="index/style.css">
</head>

<body>
 <div id="game-container">
  <button id="start-button" onclick="startGame()">Start</button>
 </div>
 <script src="index/src.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Though the elements disappear (because of opacity), they are not deleted, and the setInterval never ends.  Help, please!!!

Comment: `logoInterval` is declared in a different function scope. You’ll need to declare it in an outside scope.

Comment: Could you please, first narrow it down to a minimal working example, i.e. a piece of code such that it's enough to reproduce the problem without all the unnecessary structures, styles and so on. Probably, you could also help yourself to find the error, if you at least try to reproduce it in a small, self-contained environment.

Comment: I believe that that is as much as I can delete.  It was a lot.  Sorry.

Comment: I tried making logoInterval global, but the fade stopped working.

Comment: Does an element have to be defined in HTML to be deleted? (because the button delete works)

Comment: Do some debugging. Is `professorOpen` ever called? Does `logoOpacity` end up every being 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems.

1) `logoOpacity` is never 0. If you log the output you'll see:

```
.8
0.7000000000000001
0.6000000000000001
0.5000000000000001
0.40000000000000013
0.30000000000000016
0.20000000000000015
0.10000000000000014
1.3877787807814457e-16
```

You can see that it gets really, really, really close to 0, but not quite. This isn't particularly intuitive, it's got to do with how computers store floating point numbers, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) if you're interested.

2) logoInterval is local to the function, so `professOpen` can't "see" the variable. You can clear the interval inside the interval itself, no need to push it off to some other function.

Something like this:

```
var gameContainer = document.getElementById("game-container");

function startGame() {
    var startButton = document.getElementById("start-button");
    gameContainer.removeChild(startButton); //button disappears

    var logo = document.createElement("IMG");
    logo.src = "http://img.qj.net/uploads/articles_module/2048/poke_2Dlogo.gif";
    gameContainer.appendChild(logo);
    logo.id = "logo"; //logo appears
    var sublogo = document.createElement("P");
    var sublogoText = document.createTextNode("Yellow Diamond Version");
    sublogo.appendChild(sublogoText);
    gameContainer.appendChild(sublogo);
    sublogo.id = "sub-logo";
    var sublogoImg = document.createElement("IMG");
    sublogoImg.src = "https://41.media.tumblr.com/6f25c533c98bfc58790eba699862437d/tumblr_inline_o0nqr4s49p1sp23ws_540.png"
    gameContainer.appendChild(sublogoImg);
    sublogoImg.id = "sub-logo-img";

    setTimeout(preLogoFade, 3000);

    function preLogoFade() {
        var logoOpacity = 90;
        var logoInterval = setInterval(function() {
            LogoFade()
        }, 100);

        function LogoFade() {
            var styleOpac = logoOpacity / 100;
            logo.style.opacity = styleOpac;
            sublogo.style.opacity = styleOpac;
            sublogoImg.style.opacity = styleOpac;
            logoOpacity -= 10;
            if (logoOpacity == 0) {
                gameContainer.removeChild(logo);
                gameContainer.removeChild(sublogo);
                gameContainer.removeChild(sublogoImg);
                clearInterval(logoInterval);
                professorOpen();
            }
        } //LogoFade Function End
    } //preLogoFade Function End
} //startGame Function End

function professorOpen() {
    gameContainer.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/steven-universe/images/9/90/Yellow_Diamond_by_Lenhi.png/revision/latest?cb=20160109203916)";
}
startGame();
```

Comment: Would this prevent professorOpen from being used (because the setInterval would end)?  That's why I moved clearInterval.  Am I right or am I extremely wrong?

Comment: `professOpen` was never called because of the opacity equality issue. Once that is fixed, `professOpen` would never be able to clear the interval, because it doesn't have access to `logoInterval`.

Comment: I wasn't sure if clearInterval would stop the function call from ever happening, but it worked, so, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem I cannot identify. logoOpacity is never equal to zero on my machine. I changed '==' to <= and that seemed to work.

Your next problem is that SetInterval is not stopping even after the childnodes are gone. logoInterval is out of Scope in the function openProfessor. You either have to make it a global or include openprofessor function in logoFade.

To see this problem add a few alert(logoOpacity); lines in (don't forget to increase your interval timing or you can't stop it ... not saying I did that... but I won't say I didn't either.)

Here are the changes I found that work.

```
var gameContainer = document.getElementById("game-container");
var logoInterval;
function startGame() {
...
            logoOpacity -= .1;
            if (logoOpacity < .1) {
                gameContainer.removeChild(logo);
                gameContainer.removeChild(sublogo);
                gameContainer.removeChild(sublogoImg);
                professorOpen();
            }
        }                                       //LogoFade Function End
    }                                               //preLogoFade Function End
}                                                   //startGame Function End

function professorOpen() {
    alert("openProfessor");
    clearInterval(logoInterval);
    var BodyID = document.getElementById("BodyID")
    BodyID.style.backgroundImage="url(http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/steven-universe/images/9/90/Yellow_Diamond_by_Lenhi.png/revision/latest?cb=20160109203916)";


}
```

Comment: When I did that, the professorOpen() function DID begin to work!  Thank you!  Unfortunately, the background-image did not appear.  Inspect Element told me it could not find the variable "logo" in removeChild() nor "logoInterval" in clearInterval(), which I sort-of understand since the var is in a different function.  But, as I said above, when I made "logoInterval" global, the fade stopped working.  But, thanks for the help!!

Comment: No problem I have done so little js, it was kind of fun to play with.it was pretty wierd .8-.1=.70000000001

Comment: Alerting the opacity taught me something important.  When I subtracted 1, the page subtracted something closer to .99999999999    I find that ridiculous but good to know.  Thanks for the help.  Now I only need to change logoInterval.

Comment: I know what you did when you tried the global. It needs to be like this:        
var logoInterval;         You can't assign a value to it at the global level (at least not one you want)

Comment: For some reason, perhaps that the div is empty the background image is not showing. You could id the <body id="BodyID"> then use  var BodyID=document.getElementById("BodyID")
    BodyID.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/steven-universe/images/9/90/Yellow_Diamond_by_Lenhi.png/revision/latest?cb=20160109203916)";

Comment: The background image worked when I fixed the clearInterval(), but multas gratias!